# Text box does not show vertical bar when clicked in Win 7

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a Windows Desktop App built using c# VS 2013. A form in the app contains 2 text boxes which are used for text data input. On Win 10 both textboxes display a vertical bar when clicked indicating that they are accepting text. On Win 7 only one of the textboxes displays the vertical bar when clicked. No bar appears in the other, although it accepts text like the first one. The only significant difference between the properties of the two text boxes is the one which does not show the bar has alignment set to Centre in design mode, whereas the other has the alignment set in code.

Can anyone suggest a way of getting the bar to show in the textbox for Win 7?

Comment: A) WinForms or WPF? B) Please add your code. [mcve]

Comment: It is a Winforms app. Code is far too large & complex to post. I have found that showing a dialog box causes the cursor bar to appear when the dialog box is closed.

Comment: Showing only one of the forms with a ShowDialog command causes the bar cursor to appear. Other forms shown with this command do not result in the cursor appearing.

Comment: The blinking vertical bar is often referred to as the caret, or input cursor, and its absence is a frequent problem. I have found that a function which increases the height of the textbox makes the caret appear. When the caret is not shown, any centered text in the textbox does not move when the width of the textbox is changed. When the caret is shown, it does move. Once the caret is shown due to the showing and closing of a particular form, the caret is present irrespective of textbox height. Calling the User32.dll function ShowCaret on textbox click event does not make the caret appear.

Comment: The problem also appears on one computer running Win 8.1 but not on another computer also running Win 8.1. The .NetFramework version for the Win 7 machine is 4.7.1, but a machine running Win8.1 and .Net Framework 4.7.1 does not show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The caret disappears in a text box if the font size is too large compared to the textbox height. Changing the font size in the text box on the computer where the caret was not shown, which was 36 pixels high, from 16.2 to 12.7 points results in caret appearing as expected. In the Dev machine where the problem did not appear the Display Scale Size was 125% rather than 100%. Using a font size of 16.2 points in a text box with height 36 pixels for the text box with a Display Scale set to 100% results in the caret not appearing. Reducing the font size to 12.7 points results in the caret appearing for a Display Scale Size of 100%. It seems as though there is a ratio of textbox height to font size below which the caret is not shown for a given Display Scale, even though the entered text is shown.